# how to write a commant for output of a particular group?

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, printf, select

> ```
> Reading file prod1.tpr, VERSION 2019.6 (single precision)
> Reading file prod1.tpr, VERSION 2019.6 (single precision)
> Select a group of reference atoms and a group of molecules to be ordered:
> Group     0 (         System) has 56000 elements
> Group     1 (          Other) has 56000 elements
> Group     2 (           DPPC) has 26000 elements
> Group     3 (           TIP3) has 30000 elements
> Group     4 (     Up_Choline) has  2000 elements
> Group     5 (    Low_Choline) has  2000 elements
> Group     6 (         Up_PO4) has   500 elements
> Group     7 (        Low_PO4) has   500 elements
> Group     8 (    Up_Glycerol) has  1100 elements
> Group     9 (   Low_Glycerol) has  1100 elements
> Select a group:
> ```

Is this possible to give the input for the particular group inside the shell script So no need to select a number for a particular group in the terminal  ?
If yes then how will be the format to select a particular group in shell script?

Comment: If you need to hand over input multiple times in a program/script, the universal solution would be creating an `expect`-script. An introductionary guide to be found [here](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the command reads user input from it's standard input, it should just be a matter  of sending the input you want to feed it via a pipe, like:

```
echo 4 | your-command
```

So your-command will read `4<newline>` from its stdin which here is the reading end of a pipe. That's the same 2 characters that it would have read from some `/dev/pts/<n>` file if you had run in from a terminal and had entered <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.